# Does it make a difference using multiple setter functions vs a single generic one?

Tags: solidity, gas-price, function, enum

Let's say I have an `enum` and set the default:

```
enum Status {
    INACTIVE,
    FAIL,
    SUCCESS,
    PENDING
}

Status public myStatus = Status.INACTIVE;
```

I'm wondering if one approach to updating `myStatus` is "better" than the other in terms of gas and just best practice:

**Approach A**

Have one generic setter function that accepts a value:

```
function setStatus(uint256 _status) external onlyOwner {
    require(_status <= uint256(Status.PENDING), "Status out of bounds");
    myStatus = Status(_status);
}
```

**Approach B**

Have individual setter functions:

```
function setStatusToInactive() external onlyOwner {
    myStatus = Status.INACTIVE;
}

function setStatusToFail() external onlyOwner {
    myStatus = Status.FAIL;
}

function setStatusToSuccess() external onlyOwner {
    myStatus = Status.SUCCESS;
}

function setStatusToPending() external onlyOwner {
    myStatus = Status.PENDING;
}
```

With **B**, you can strictly control the setters and have no need for `require` statements. Any front-end interacting with the contract will not need to be aware of the enum and instead just call the appropriate function.

With **A**, does it cost less gas to deploy? Does it have any effect? Should you not add "unnecessary" functions like in **B**? In a scenario where there are many values in the enum, **B** becomes unmanageable if you need a setter for every one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with **A** and an `enum`.

```
function setStatus(Status status) external onlyOwner {
  myStatus = status;
  emit ... 
}
```

By casting the input as an `enum` you get a similar effect as your `require` and you avoid the convoluted type conversions. The internal `enum` creates an external `uint8` because the list "fits" in a `uint8`. From a client-side perspective, they pass 0, 1, 2, etc. as a `uint8` as you would expect.

While there are arguments for **B** around user-friendliness in some cases (enable/disable?), that's a subjective call. It will increase deployment cost to increase the contract size so I would avoid using it for long lists. General heuristic  - always aim for simplicity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that the client could pass a `uint8` and the contract function would cast based on the parameter type (guessing that is specific to enum in solidity). Thanks for your help!